# Recover deleted VeraCrypt partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, truecrypt, partition-recovery, veracrypt

I have an external 1TB HDD with a NTFS partition and a Veracrypt one, or had, at least.
I did a messy move trying to use the NTFS one to make a windows recovery media, to find out the hard way that the f*&#ng Win10 media creator rebuilds the entire disk partition table instead of just placing the files into the one Ive selected [sigh].

Assuming that the encrypted partition is still there, untouched, recovering the MBR would solve my problem. But after reading in the [VC volume format spec](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VeraCrypt%20Volume%20Format%20Specification) the phrase

> VeraCrypt volumes have no 
>   "signature" or ID strings. Until decrypted, they appear to consist
>   solely of random data.

it seem that partition recovery tools will simply not find where it is.
Yet, using the EaseUS recovery tool the NTFS one was found! (I did not recovered it yet) 
The tool found it on the end of the disk, it seems, with the correct size and label.

The disk is pretty new, and the NTFS partition is mostly unused, so it probably contains zeroes outside the VC partition boundaries.
In theory I could find the beginning sector and rebuild the partition table, but reading [undo-diskpart-clean](https://superuser.com/questions/906184/undo-diskpart-clean) and [how-to-recover-truecrypt-partition-deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/658115/how-to-recover-truecrypt-partition-deleted-with-windows-disk-manager) won't give me a painless solution for that.

Question, if I restore the NTFS one, create a new raw partition with the unused space, will VC be able to mount it?

How do I proceed now to make sure I don't destroy it for good?

Comment: I've recovered the NTFS partition and marked the remaining of the disc as  a RAW partition. VereCrypt was unable to mount it or to restore the volume header (that should have a clone at the end of it). Any ideas? Even untested crazy ones?

Comment: I accidentially deleted the partition and could get my data back as followed: Create the partition exactly as it was. Quickformatted with same NTFS properties. Then restored the key header from the same volume with the Veracrypt option. After that with a file recovery tool (like EaseUs or MiniTool Partition Wizard) I gained my files back.