# Recover accidentally deleted VeraCrypt container

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, truecrypt, veracrypt

I created a VeraCrypt container and stored some files, but today I noticed that I mistakenly deleted that container from disk about 3 days ago. The size of the container was 30GB.

What are my options now to recover that container?

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1067056/recover-deleted-veracrypt-partition) similar question but was not able to follow through.
I also don't have any experience using recovery softwares like Recuva or testdisk.
The files are important to me. If anyone can guide me with some specific method or software, it would be really helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

Comment: The chances of recovery are extremely slim to none at all. Reason: Any encrypted data must be recovered exactly as it originally was, in a pristine condition. Otherwise it won't decrypt, it's just garbled meaningless bits and bytes (the reason why we use encryption in the first place). It could have been recovered provided absolutely nothing was overwritten. After 3 days when supposedly you used the OS normally? Forget it. Many megas have be overwritten making any recovery moot, end of story. If data is important you should have backups, a lesson learned, hopefully.

Comment: Are you in Windows? If yes, you might look in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: @harrymc - Windows does normally keep a 30 GB file in the recycle bin.  Files of that size are typically permanently deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound: I currently have in mine 3 files of around 160 GB each.

Comment: @harrymc I actually permanently deleted it, so no hope there

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Yes i understand that. I have made peace with the fact that the data in gone for good now.

Comment: First rule: Do not modify anything on the disk in the meantime. Now, you need a recovery tool. I suggest [MiniTool Data Recovery](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/), although the free version only does 1 GB.

Comment: @harrymc will this software work??
I have not changed anything on the disk, but as the container was encrypted do you think this software will be able to recover the whole container?
I can give it a try

Comment: Yes, you may certainly try.